# jQuery Selectbox plugin conflict

Tags: jquery, magento, conflict

Hi i'm using **jQuery Selectbox plugin** to my magento site (got it from http://code.google.com/p/select-box/)

After adding this plugin my menu dropdown and event timer is not working properly. To remove this conflict i tried by changing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#language").selectbox();
});
</script>
```

To

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#language").selectbox();
});

})(jQuery);  </script>
```

But no luck so far. Please give me your idea to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try replacing $ with jQuery, in most cases that does fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I replaced $ with jQuery but still it's same... Any other suggestions ????

Answer (score 1):

I just added jQuery.noConflict(); at the end of my js files.
Original source : http://blog.ecommercesoftwaresolutionsonline.com/archives/174/how-to-avoid-the-conflict-while-using-jquery-functionality-in-magento.html

Thanks a ton.